# Why is my JFrame blank?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I'm really going crazy with this code. I need to know what im doing wrong? I'm supposed to get 3 textfields and one textarea showing and when I execute I just get one grey box. I cannot see the textfields and the textarea, not even the button. What is wrong? Why is my JFrame blank?! thanks

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.lang.Integer;



public class MinVara extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    //Skapar upp instans variabler (instansvariabler in the body of the class
    //but outside the bodies of the class methods

  private String namn;
  private int nummer;
 private double pris; 



    //Skapar konstruktor för minvara.Like amethod, a constructor’s parameterlist 
 //specifies the data it requires to perform its task
 //An important difference between constructors and methods is that constructors
//cannot return values, so they cannot specify a return type 
 //(not even void). Normally, constructors are declared public.

 public MinVara(String namn, int nummer, double pris) { 
        this.namn = namn; //this "Det här objektet name"
        this.nummer = nummer; //"" 
        this.pris = pris;//""

       // slut constructor 
        initComponents();
     }



    //Skapa ett nytt minvara objekt genom att kalla på en konstruktor
     MinVara var = new MinVara(namn, nummer, pris); //


    @Override
public void setName(String namn)  {  
        this.namn = namn; } //store the string name

 public void setAntal (int nummer)  {  
        this.nummer = nummer;  }

    public void  setPrice (double pris) { 
        this.pris = pris; } 



    @Override
    public String getName() {    
        return this.namn;} 


    public int getAntal() {    
        return this.nummer; }     

    public double getPrice() {   
        return this.pris; } 


    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jColorChooser1 = new javax.swing.JColorChooser();
        jColorChooser2 = new javax.swing.JColorChooser();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        jTextField2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton1.setText("OK");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("Namn");

        jLabel2.setText("Pris");

        jLabel3.setText("Antal");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 90, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 90, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 90, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 67, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 44, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 239, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(27, 27, 27))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 249, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addGap(8, 8, 8)
                        .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addGap(8, 8, 8)
                        .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(40, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

 jTextArea1.setText(null); //tömmer textarean

//variablar till textfälten. omvandla string till int och double.
 this.namn =  jTextField1.getText();
 var.setName(namn);
 jTextArea1.append("Namnet på varan : " +var.getName());

 this.nummer  = Integer.parseInt( jTextField3.getText() );
var.setAntal(nummer);
 jTextArea1.append("Antal varor : " + var.getAntal() );

 this.pris = Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText() );
 var.setPrice(pris);
 jTextArea1.append("Pris : " + var.getPrice());







    }                                        

    private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    }                                           

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
         * Set the Nimbus look and feel
         */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MinVara.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MinVara.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MinVara.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MinVara.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Resultat");
            JPanel jPanel1 = new JPanel();

            frame.getContentPane().add(jPanel1);
            frame.pack();

       frame.setSize(400,400);
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JColorChooser jColorChooser1;
    private javax.swing.JColorChooser jColorChooser2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: what a big code, the problem is that you are creating a JFrame empty rather than creating your MinVara instance, also don't know why you modify default matisse main

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough.

Comment: Big codes because of default code that follows when i design in netbeans. Sorry for that but didnt wanna chop anything off in case it was important for you guys to see. Anyhow im gonna check in to this MinVara instance.thanks

Answer (score 5):

Probably because of this code:

```
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Resultat");
        JPanel jPanel1 = new JPanel();

        frame.getContentPane().add(jPanel1);
        frame.pack();

   frame.setSize(400,400);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.setVisible(true);
```

You're adding a blank panel to your JFrame and you don't modify it after that.  Your class extends a JFrame, but I don't see you trying to show `MinVara`.  Perhaps you meant to say `JFrame frame = new MinVara(...)` here.

Comment: Would it work to have a JFrame without JPanel?
No to say JFrame frame = new MinVara creates an constructor error stating that minvara in class minvara cannot be applied to given types. @tieTYT

Comment: If that's the exact code you're typing, that's not valid Java.  I think you should learn more about the Java language first.  Specifically, how to call constructors.  If it isn't the exact code you're typing, you should show us the exact code.

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean. Yes this is the exact code im typing that im showing you guys here. If my costructors is the problem with this code it would be very nice if you then tell me that this is the reason that my frame is blank @tieTYT